# User-accessible folder for Click-Once applications

Tags: winforms, error-handling

In a WinForms application written in C# and being deployed via Click-Once, if certain errors happen, I write information to a log file. I'm setting the path for that log file as such:

```
private static string strAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
private static readonly string strLogFile = "Log File.txt";
private static readonly string strPathToLogFile = strAppPath + "\\" + strLogFile;
```

When an error happens, I am also showing a messagebox instructing the user to locate the file (I'm providing the strPathToLogFile variable in the message).

However, in testing it I found that the path is quite user-unfriendly, to say the least. It looks something like this:

[image]

Is there a better/recommended place to save the file to? I can't save it to a user folder, as multiple users will be running the application.

Answer (score -1):

There are several solutions

1. put the log in a simple path like c:\logs\log.txt
2. add button in the message box that opens the folder of the file
3. add button in the message box that sand the logs to the developer automatically

Comment: The c:\logs folder is unlikely to be user-writable in environments where ClickOnce is the preferred deployment.

Comment: The user documents folder might be okay, but then you still end up showing a path like `C:\Users\{username}\Documents\MyAppLogs\log.txt`. This is still longer and less friendly than it needs to be. When it comes down to it (and this makes me sad), showing users file paths at all is something of anachronism in modern apps.

Comment: And so we come to options two or three. Again, given ClickOnce, option 3 may not be possible. So we're left #2. The downside here is you can't put that in a simple message box... this requires an completely different form. Maybe forcing the folder open on the desktop instead?

Comment: I have no experience with a click-one but why you can't simply post to the developer server?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I pretty much came to the same conclusions as you: #1 is out due to who will be using the application, #3 is more work that I'd like to spend on it. So #2 might be the best option, but to just automatically open the folder containing the file or the file itself.  Thanks!